# magento 1.9, how sort products by stock

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

i have this code

```
$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->setPageSize(5)
            ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', array('in' => array('4', '12')))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gteq'=>80))
            ->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );

        $product_model->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('_inventory_table' => $product_model->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
            "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",
            array('is_in_stock', 0)
        );
```

I want to get all the products that out_of_stock

How can this be done in my request?

and how can my code be optimized?

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line to end to sort by qty desc:

```
$product_model->getSelect()->order('qty DESC');
```